# Articulate: Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL Error

Tags: html

I am trying to play story_html5.html video from Amazon Cloud fount in a IFrame, "story.html" is working fine in Iframe, but when use story_html5.html, it gives error.

Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL "URL1" from frame with URL "URL2". Domains, protocols and ports must match.

Please let me know about the solution.

Thanks,
Laxmilal Menaria

Comment: without some code to look at it's very hard to help. can you point us to a hosted sample or something on jsFiddle

Answer (score 0):

I believe the html5 version of the file may be called once the code determines it's needed. Based on this, your personal code may look like it's trying to hijack the process and causing the exception. W/out the exact code you're working with though, it's hard to say. This is just based on my pulling apart some of the files a while back.